# Laravel 5 Views Structure

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I added a bootstrap template to laravel 5 `Resources directory`.
And added only the `index.php` to `views` in `Resources`.

The `index.php` file is pointing the files like :

`<link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

And its not loading.

In my `routes.php` i am loading :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
  return view('index');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see in the code, **ViewFinder** does a case sensitive search for a template based on whatever you provide to the **view()** helper.

Pass **Index** to **view()** instead of **index** or change the template  name from **Index.php** to **index.php**.

If your view renders correctly, but **CSS** file is not loaded, it means it's inaccessible to the browser. Files that are not returned via Laravel need to end up somewhere in **/public** folder so that web server can read them and return to the browser. You need to place them there manually or using some build toos (gulp, grunt, ...).

In your case, your bootstrap file must end up in **public/bootstrap/css/** folder.

You could also fetch the **bootstrap** file from a CDN by using one of absolute URLs you can find here: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/, e.g.:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Yeah sorry. But that is fine in the project. Only the bootstrap style-sheet is not loading.

Comment: Where do you keep the bootstrap file in your project?

Comment: bootstrap folder is in the `resources` folder and `index.php` is in views.
Remember i am using Laravel 5.

Comment: Thanks buddy ! Awesome

Answer (score 1):

Add bootstrap files inside the public folder. Suppose your bootstrap file inside the `laravel\public\css` then:

```
{!! Html::style('css/style.css') !!}
```

and jquery files `laravel\public\js`

```
{!! Html::script('js/jquery.js') !!}
```